# Valid reasons for a new moderator unfreezing his inactive room?

Tags: discussion, chat, moderators

I noticed that one of the new moderators decided to [unfreeze a room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34209098#34209098) that was inactive for some time.  IIRC, the room was frozen because it was (almost entirely) just a feed of site-questions meant to obfuscate the fact that it was inactive.

This wouldn't be strange, except for the fact that the moderator is the owner of the room, and he had originally created it in protest after being repeatedly antagonistic towards members of an existing room because he was not made a room owner.  I brought up this concern, rather directly, during the nomination phase, hoping for a tidy resolution or assuaging of my concern that I'd be posting a message like this on meta, but now we're here.

Am I reading too much into this or is this strange behavior for a moderator to take immediately after getting a diamond?

Mea culpa.  Take care all :)

Comment: First meta question about a new moderator: within 24 hours. Is this a record? :D

Comment: From a quick look through the transcripts, the room was only ever a "dumping place" for a couple of feeds. Other than that, there really hasn't been much activity at all. Out of 1178 messages in the 1.5 years the room existed, 753 were posted by the room's owner.

Comment: The entire reason that room exists is because of the user's decline in behavior over about six months that finally got them kicked out of a different room. Then it was sustained with a similar title and tags with content-less, sporadic messages for months. This development doesn't inspire hope that the new mod's decision making process has improved.

Comment: Not that I really support the mod taking the action that they did, but why do we care?  Why is there a problem with a room existing that nobody uses, where one mod posts questions to himself that nobody ever looks at?  What was the reason the room was frozen in the first place?

Comment: @Servy The room was frozen because of site policies.  The role of a moderator is to employ said policies and to use the new permissions to maintain the site (with an implicit goal of serving others).  Actions such as these, especially in its expediency and immediacy, call the motivations of a moderator into question.  Pre-existing concerns about user behavior act as compounding factors in this case.

Comment: @tristan Saying it was closed because of "site policies" is begging the question.  What site policies did it violate to merit it being frozen?  Like I said, I don't support the mod taking the action, but I'm just curious if you care because the mod unfroze a room he owned, or because the room actually shouldn't be unfrozen.  I care about the former too, but nobody has yet given me a reason to care about the latter, and if the room actually does merit being unfrozen I only care a little bit about the owner being the one to do it.

Comment: This is an utter non-issue. Sure, it looks weird. But even as a non-mod, they could have started a new room with similar contents or asked a mod to unfreeze the room. I once asked to unfreeze a low-volume room with very sporadic conversations, and it was no issue at all. Framing the unfreezing as a violation of site policies is misleading – rooms are automatically frozen if no human posts there for some time. It's not like the freezing was a ban that was now being circumvented.

Comment: @tristan: It was frozen due to inactivity. Why not unfreeze it if users plan on using the room?

Comment: @Cerbrus it was also manually frozen at some point before that, and the user received multiple warnings from mods for *why* they were using the room (and other rooms). It's not the room itself so much as all the history around it.

Comment: @davidism: Ah, I wasn't aware of that history.

Comment: @davidism Yes, and the same mod who manually froze that room would later unfreeze it. After that, the room was automatically frozen for inactivity which was then reverted by Aaron Hall as discussed here. So, why did that first mod decide that the room was OK after all and should be unfrozen? Can you link to the “multiple warnings” and any public discussion on the original freezing & unfreezing? So far, I'm unable to find any references. I want to believe, but I won't believe source-less accusations.

Comment: I would really love to see a different moderator/employee answer this question...

Comment: Apparently my light-hearted comment was swiftly removed, so here's attempt #2: if he had just created a new room, would you have cared then? I don't think so. This is a non-issue.

Comment: @Stijn I believe that you're skipping the contextual details that make this a distinct issue.

Comment: @tristan I believe you're avoiding my question.

Comment: @Stijn I'm sorry if you feel that way, but I believe that I answered it directly.  The question, as you stated it, is not a fair representation of what's being discussed.

Comment: @tristan You haven't. It's a yes-no question, and I'm not seeing a "yes" or a "no".

Comment: Post an answer, eh @Stijn?

Comment: If he created a new room, would that be an issue? Of course not.  Is that a fair reduction of what is being discussed? No.

Comment: I honestly can't tell what you're trying to imply is wrong here.

Comment: Yeah, have a load of comments with that info been deleted or something? For those of us who missed it, can someone expand on what this travesty actually is?? Or do we need to have been in a particular chat room at a particular time to understand why these guys don't like each other?

Comment: `Is that a fair reduction of what is being discussed? No.` so basically you have a history with this specific mod (that I can't comment on, I don't know either of you nor did I vote for Aaron) and you're using an entirely harmless moderator action to bring up that history?

Comment: @Pekka웃 It's not bringing up this history.  The question is intentionally scoped because ~~e-drama~~ is time consuming.  We're pretty far down the comment chain and I believe everything that can be said about it has already been stated in triplicate.

Comment: @BSMP No, it's legitimate concern and definitively not trolling.  I know Aaron "IRL" and care about him.  Anyway!  The time spent responding to people because I, for some reason, opened a meta about this incredibly unimportant topic was the push I needed to take a look at my time budget and my lack of restraint regarding ~~internet stuff~~.

Comment: OK, this is just getting silly. Please go for a walk or something, buy a turkey, make some eggnog.

Comment: For anyone wondering about "The Conversation" (or one of them) that led to the creation of this other room, [start reading here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3624800#3624800) it goes on for a while. I'll let the users interested in reading this draw their own conclusions on the whole matter. IMO, while it is part of the reason I did not vote for said candidate, I think this whole meta question is unnecessary.

Comment: That room would have been unfrozen by a moderator if, as a regular user,  Aaron had asked for it to be unfrozen. The only thing that's changed is that now he can do it himself. It's really not worth raising a big thing about something so minor.

Comment: "...originally created it in protest after being repeatedly antagonistic towards members of an existing room because he was not made a room owner..." Sounds like a fair solution to me. Unfreezing the room is probably nothing really serious. Does one need to be a moderator for it? I guess this post is effectively just advertisement for this room.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Who cares?

Anyone with 100 reputation or more can create a new room at any time; he could've just done that. Moderators regularly unfreeze rooms upon request for members in good standing, just to save time; plenty of moderators have rooms of their own for the purpose of team discussions or "office hours", and unfreeze those periodically when they get frozen.

The purpose of freezing is to get rid of rooms that aren't being used, not punish folks for getting busy elsewhere...

That said, your real concern is that the room signals that Aaron will return to being a petty jackass over something or other with the main Python room. That would, of course, be bad. It would be bad if he wasn't a moderator, and now it would be even worse.

I trust he has better sense (and *far* too much to keep him busy) now than to do anything of the sort. But if that assumption doesn't hold, I would strongly encourage you to raise the red flag *then*—it'll carry a lot more weight if you don't jump the gun.

Comment: Thank you for this. I did not have any idea that people would get upset with me reopening a room. I'm sorry for the apparent conflict of interest, but it's something I've seen mods do over and over again for their own rooms - so as far as I know, it's something I'm *supposed* to do.

Comment: Based on the timing of the edit on Aaron's answer immediately following yours, I assume that some coaching has been done; thank you.  This isn't jumping the gun; this is smelling smoke and warning adults.  You didn't correctly infer my real concern -- it's actually that the election system rewarded someone that doesn't act earnestly (e.g. his behavior in the comments on his answer) and adding a moderator with questionable intentions.  I'm sorry, but we both know he didn't unfreeze the room for anything other than egotistical reasons.

Comment: @AaronHall it's not about re-opening the room.  Search page for "You're doing it again."  Just be honest and people will respect you for owning up to your actions.

Comment: @tristan that doesn't change the fact that criticizing someone for *unfreezing a room that they could have just recreated with the click of a button* looks pretty crazy.

Comment: *"it's actually that the election system rewarded someone that doesn't act earnestly (e.g. his behavior in the comments on his answer) and adding a moderator with questionable intentions"* ... There we have it.

Comment: @Bart tl;dr: "I don't like this moderator; I said so during the nomination phase; people didn't listen to me; now I'll use *anything* to make him look bad." 2016 elections in a nutshell, eh

Comment: @Bart; Pekka Go ahead and put whatever words in my mouth helps you go about your day, but I was talking about the action and that's an important framing detail.

Comment: @tristan I don't know any of the backstory here so I'm seeing this fresh - what's the problem exactly? Are you complaining about the action that was taken, or are you complaining that the moderator has those powers to begin with? To a neutral it looks like you're using the first to make a point of the second. Does that cover it or is there more to it?

Comment: The comment noise and people eager to try to be amusing have made it into a mud pit.  The unfortunate context matters, but the concern is centered around what I mentioned here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338337/valid-reasons-for-a-new-moderator-unfreezing-his-inactive-room/338353?noredirect=1#comment414440_338337  It's not the _what_, it's the _why_.

Comment: I don't know who you're referring to, I don't see any humour here but I'll assume you didn't mean me... Regardless, the comment you linked to doesn't explain anything in all honesty. Without real context, this looks a bit like a witch hunt from here. Feel like I have to clarify: I didn't vote for Aaron so I don't have a horse in this race

Comment: That's just careless advice, @Pekka웃. Remember the story of the boy who cried wolf? When the wolf *did* arrive, his proactive wolf-drills had the townsfolk well-prepared, and many a person thanked him over a bowl of hearty wolf-stew.

Comment: @Shog9 I mean, you did call him a "petty jackass", so would it be so wild if this was a demonstrative action?

Comment: @tristan Aaron may be  bad moderator material as you say. He also may be great moderator material. He could also change either way now that he has the job. I really don't know; as said, I know nothing about him. But this action was the wrong action to call attention to his potentially being a bad moderator, because it was not a problematic action if looked at on its own (which is the only way most of us can look at it.) That's on you.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I think he'll be a fine moderator.  He takes it seriously and is emotionally invested.  I think this _specific_ action has a smell and I brought it up.

Comment: For the record, if I am ever elected moderator, I am going to abuse the system in much more interesting and colourful ways. Promise!

Comment: @Pekka웃 let me just note that with *your* history, probably everyone will believe that you know what you're doing, even if you're walking the line. At least to me, it makes all the difference whether a shady gesture is made by someone genuine or someone with questionable posture (generally speaking, not to be applied to this specific situation).

Comment: @Shog9 Your answer, before the "That said," is bang-on.  I still think it was using mod permissions for selfish reasons, but you're right, _oh god who cares_.  Please edit so I can accept (I don't want to implicitly agree with "petty jackass")

Comment: @Andras Deak: It's all part of the plan.

Comment: @BoltClock "hmm. Why did Pekka♦ undelete all of Will's 20,000 meme comments? Weird. But it's Pekka; he must know what he's doing" ACHIEVEMENT UNLOCKED

Comment: I will put my hat in the ring of stating that having seen @AaronHall here and at Academia - I consider him very knowledgeable and a good choice for moderator. Yet, I consider the OP's question valid and - considering the history with the entirety of the Python Room - something that needs to be asked. Maybe its just timing, maybe its just that a new moderator did not realize how much his actions will be scrutinized - but the *action* just screamed at some of us who were involved in the earlier drama. Reassurance from the new mod (and Shog9 with thanks) go a long way towards rebuilding trust.

Comment: @JGreenwell what *more* reassurance do you want? Here's my nomination post: http://stackoverflow.com/election/8#post-40474659 The voters have spoken, the election is over, and I will serve the voters and users, and not let my hands be tied by baseless recriminations.

Comment: @AaronHall What is given here by Shog9 is a start (administrative side) - that if a moderator (any, not just you) steps over a line or can be shown to not acting within the interest of the community then steps can be taken and procedures are in place. As to yourself specifically, "rebuilding" is a slower process so it just time and choices which show trust was placed in the correct hands. [Servy's comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338337/valid-reasons-for-a-new-moderator-unfreezing-his-inactive-room/338353?noredirect=1#comment414452_338347) is close to my thoughts on your post

Comment: @AaronHall there are many ways you can defend yourself and your actions, but "*the voters have spoken*" is entirely irrelevant, and in light of recent voting events in the world, I would concentrate on your own side rather than on the results of various voting systems. I'm not trying to stretch on this debate, everybody has already said what they wanted; this is only some friendly suggestion for rhetoric.

Comment: December 25th, this room was [Frozen again](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/81671/2016/12/25) for inactivity. December 31st, @AaronHall [unfroze it again](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/81671/2016/12/31). At this point, I'm wondering, ___"What's the point?"___ The only messages in there since the room was [first unfrozen](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/81671/2016/11/23), are a couple of greetings, and someone asking _"anyone here?"_ The room isn't going to become more active by just "existing".

Comment: Is there a room with moderators in order to contact them easily?

Answer (score 33):

> Am I reading too much into this or is this strange behavior for a moderator to take immediately after getting a diamond?

You're reading much in it. That is for sure. But it can't be denied that there was some history between the room you originated from and that other room.

As there is not much to go on, I think it had been better if this stayed history. However, that does need that all involved in the history making process play by that rule.

My gut feeling says that the moderator underestimated how much their actions are scrutinized by a dedicated group of users, specially in relation to that chatroom. It shows that their community sensibility needs adjustment.

On the other hand I find it difficult to decide if the concern you raise is valid. After all, you are kind of representing *the other side* and the occasional meta visitor doesn't have much means to get an unbiased view. Some readers might interpret your question as an attempt to give the moderator a false start.

At this moment I don't think there is much of issue in the unfreezing of said chatroom in itself. The moderator should have known it could raise some eyebrows. That is a lesson for the mod. But moderators are in the end also elected by more than just you and me. I would assume good faith for now.

Comment: "*[It shows that their community sensibility needs adjustment.*". Let's hope he'll do just that, something tells me that wouldn't be too bad.

Comment: "It shows that their community sensibility needs adjustment." Actually I disagree. Avoiding everything that potentially offends someone results in not doing anything. The community has to live with elected moderators using the site and leaving impressions. We shouldn't check every single moderator bit of action scrupulously or we won't have many moderators in the future - apart from the waste of resources doing that. There is a balance somewhere.

Comment: @Trilarion That specific sentence was formulated that way to express that a moderator needs to understand that when they were part of a conflict in the past between them and a group of users, the moderator better refrains from taking an action that gives the impression they didn't let go of what happened back then. There is a balance somewhere indeed. And plenty of other mods to consult: *hey, that room I created when I got fed up with those other users is frozen. Do you think it is wise if it is unfrozen and if so, can you do it for me?*

Comment: What rene described is the kind of introspection and humility that should be the bare minimum for moderators. Hopefully these skills can be improved by learning.